# Правильна ли эта вёрстка?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, инспекция-кода

Здравствуйте. 
Во время вёрстки первого для меня макета появились вопросы. Расположил левый блок, затем основную часть, потом - правую. [Сверстал кое-как](http://mysolaris.xyz/Interica.html). Вопросы следующие:

1. Макет основан на слайдере. Мои навыки JS почти нулевые. Подсказали
   fullpage.js. Вся документация на английском. Какие нужны навыки JS,
   чтобы посадить сайт на слайдер? Непонятно, каким образом верстать
   следующие страницы макета после этой.
2. Правильно ли таким образом располагать блоки на странице? Использую флексбоксы, каким образом поместить блоки с текстом и иконками в нижнем левом углу экрана?
3. В макете есть тень для нижней части экрана, однако никак не могу поместить её именно так, как это указано в макете psd.
4. Присутствует небольшая, но раздражающая, горизонтальная прокрутка. Можно применить overflow-z: hidden, однако таким образом пропадет правая часть экрана на мобильных устройствах =>
5. Несмотря на то, что это мой первый макет, не собираюсь бросать его потому, что появились трудности со слайдером и пр. В мыслях - доверстать до конца кроссбраузерно и адаптивно.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:100,300,400,700');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i');
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background: url("background.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: white;
  width: 1360px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.left-side,
.main {
  position: absolute;
  height: 768px;
}

.left-side {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 110px;
  background: #fff;
  left: 0;
  max-height: 768px;
  max-width: 110px;
}

.left-side_logo {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 130px;
  width: 17px;
  height: 130px;
}

.left-side_bottom {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 130px;
  width: 17px;
  height: 130px;
}

.left-side_bottom img {
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

.left-side_bottom img:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}

.left-side_center {
  position: relative;
}

.selected {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
}

.opa {
  opacity: 0.72;
}

.main {
  left: 110px;
}

.main>div {
  position: relative;
}

.main_play {
  left: 15px;
  top: 525px;
}

.main_play img {
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

.main_play img:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}

.main_company-name {
  font-style: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  top: 390px;
  left: 90px;
}

.main_slogan {
  font-style: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  top: 340px;
  left: 90px;
}

.main_lines {
  left: 90px;
  top: 380px;
}

.main_calc {
  left: 1200px;
  top: -300px;
  width: 50px;
}

.main_calc,
.main_wite-us,
.main_download,
.main_call-us,
.main_play,
.main_lines,
.left-side_logo,
.left-side_bottom,
.left-side_selected,
.left-side_center img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main_calc img {
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

.main_calc img:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}

.main_wite-us {
  left: 1200px;
  top: -250px;
  width: 50px;
}

.main_wite-us img {
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

.main_wite-us img:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}

.main_download {
  left: 1200px;
  top: -200px;
  width: 50px;
}

.main_download img {
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

.main_download img:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}

.main_rotate-text {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  left: 1000px;
  top: 50px;
}

.main_call-us {
  left: 1185px;
  top: 250px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Interica</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="main_play">
        <a href="#"><img src="play.png" title="Title"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="main_company-name">
        <h1>INTERICA</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="main_slogan">
        <p>We are an association of professionals who are ready <br /> to assist you in matters of redevelopment</p>
      </div>
      <div class="main_lines">
        <img src="-.png">
        <img src="-.png">
        <img src="-.png">
        <img src="-.png">
      </div>
      <div class="main_calc">
        <a href="#"><img src="calc.png" title="Calculator"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="main_wite-us">
        <a href="#"><img src="wite-us.png" title="Wite Us"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="main_download">
        <a href="#"><img src="download.png" title="Download"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="main_rotate-text">
        <p>The Interior Agency Theme</p>
      </div>
      <div class="main_call-us">
        <a href="#"><img src="call-us.png"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="left-side">
      <div class="left-side_logo">
        <a href="#"><img src="logo.jpg" title="Interica"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="left-side_center">
        <a href="#"><img src="Elipse-gray.png" class="opa"></a>
        <img src="Elipse.png" class="selected">
      </div>
      <div class="left-side_bottom">
        <a href="#"><img src="share.png" title="Share"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: Как я это вижу]

Comment: Пожалуйста, оформите код страницы сниппетом (кнопка `<>`) непосредственно в вопросе. Ссылка на внешний ресурс однажды станет невалидной, и вопрос будет бесполезен для всех.

Comment: @Nofate, изменил содержание вопроса. Так должно выглядеть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Навыков `JS` здесь и не надо, т.к. на сам слайдер максимум уйдёт до `30` **строчек кода**. Если есть **документация** - просто переведите её с английского на русский.
2. На счет верстки блоками...Пробуйте изучить `Bootstrap`. Адаптивность в нём гарантирована.
3. Чтобы не было полос прокрутки, нужно указать `max-width` для основной части.